# Question on infinite T4 topological space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, separation-axioms

I have this question here from a course in general topology course I could not answer all of so I am asking here, it reads:

> Let $ (X,\tau) $ be a $ T_4 $ topological space (normal Hausdorff) with $ |X| = \infty $
>
> a. We are to define the definition of a $ T_4 $ topological space. Ok I know what the definition of this space is.
>
> b. We are to prove the existence of disjoint open non empty sets, U and V with U an infinite set.
>
> c. We are to prove in X there exists an infinite sequence of disjoint open sets (non empty).
>
> d. We are to prove the space of continuous bounded real valued functions $ C_b(X,R) $ with the supremum norm $ L^{\infty} $ is not locally compact.

Ok so what I have tried to do in part b was try to find an infinite closed set and with another singleton a closed set we can certainly separate them with disjoint open sets due to normality of X but besides singletons and finite sets I do not know of closed sets...
On part c I am stuck as I could not construct such a sequence and part d is a complete mystery to me. I thank you for all the help

Comment: Before I start thinking, is $T_4$ for you stronger than $T_2$ or incomparable?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis from the context, it must be the nomenclature that $T_4$ implies all $T_k$ for $k < 4$, otherwise the assertions would be wrong. So it's a normal space in the other common nomenclature.

Comment: Yes by $ T_4  $ I mean inclusive of all lower separation axioms

Comment: For part b), start with two distinct points $x,y$. By $T_2$ there are disjoint open neighbourhoods $U,V$ of the two points. If one of the two open neighbourhoods is infinite, you're done. Otherwise, have you an idea how to get an infinite closed set?

Comment: Thanks to both of you I think they are feasible for me know but part d is still a mystery to me

Comment: @bof I am sorry but could you show me part c also besides d? Seeing as how I only know closed subset of T4 is T4 but not for general subspaces

Comment: @AbeerAbassi I'm sorry. You're right, subspace of T4 is not T4. But a subspace of a T3 space is T3, and I think the argument for part b only uses T3.

Comment: @bof thanks yes makes sense now but could you please help me establish part d now? That is all that's left for me in this question

Comment: As @bof says, the argument for b) uses only $T_3$, so we get c) from inductively applying b). For d), use $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ and c) to deduce that $C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @DanielFischer : OK that makes sense but what if I do show it is infinite dimensional what does that mean regarding local compactness or lack thereof

Comment: If you don't already (officially) know that a Hausdorff topological vector space (or less general a normed space) is locally compact if and only if it is finite-dimensional, then use $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ and c) to get a sequence in the ball $B_{\varepsilon}(0) \subset C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$ that has no unifomly convergent subsequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Thanks mate got it now